# How to submit an HTML form on loading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

How to submit this form without using submit button. I want to submit it in loading this form,

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="../somePage" method="post">
    Please Waite...
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" id="uname" value="<?php echo $uname;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="<?php echo $price;?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: You want to submit the form as soon as the page loads? What's the point of that?

Comment: @MattBall. For example, it allows using a form to gather private customer data, check it for correctness and if what they want is available (because a lot of time can lapse between when a person accesses a page and when they click the *Buy* button), supply a form that contains PayPal-specific data that submits immediately (before they delay some more) to show PayPal's payment approval page to them, otherwise go back to the original page with what's incorrect or out of stock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#frm1").submit();
});
```

Comment: this way is only for JQuery use

Answer (score 50):

You **don't need Jquery** here!
The **simplest solution** here is (based on the answer from charles):

```
<html>
<body onload="document.frm1.submit()">
   <form action="http://www.google.com" name="frm1">
      <input type="hidden" name="q" value="Hello world" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try also using below script

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function load()
{
document.frm1.submit()
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<form action="http://www.google.com" id="frm1" name="frm1">
<input type="text" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by using simple one line JavaScript code and also be careful that if JavaScript is turned off it will not work. The below code will do it's job if JavaScript is turned off.

Turn off JavaScript and run the code on you own file to know it's full function.(If you turn off JavaScript here, the below Code Snippet will not work)

```css
.noscript-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="document.getElementById('payment-form').submit();">

  <div align="center">
    <h1>
      Please Waite... You Will be Redirected Shortly<br/>
      Don't Refresh or Press Back 
    </h1>
  </div>

  <form method='post' action='acction.php' id='payment-form'>
    <input type='hidden' name='field-name' value='field-value'>
     <input type='hidden' name='field-name2' value='field-value2'>
    <noscript>
      <div align="center" class="noscript-error">Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!.
        <br>Kindly submit it manually
        <input type='submit' value='Submit Now' />
      </div>
    </noscript>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: i need ur help related to this..Can u help me

Comment: Sure, I will help you.

Comment: i got a value using this  var stud_pay_mode= $(this).find('input.stuPaymode').val();

Comment: try this $('option[value="'+stud_pay_mode+'"]').prop('selected', true);

Comment: Any id in my dropdown..?

Comment: You no need specify id for options, you can select using value itself.Here is the sample https://jsfiddle.net/fff02pde/3/ , have a look at it and verify you are looking something like this. If you need more specific for your problem, you have to show you code.

Answer (score 4):

using javascript

```
 <form id="frm1" action="file.php"></form>
    <script>document.getElementById('frm1').submit();</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed the closing tag for the input fields, and you can choose any one of the events, ex: onload, onclick etc.

**(a) Onload event:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#frm1').submit();
});
</script>
```

**(b) Onclick Event:**

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="../somePage" method="post">
    Please Waite... 
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" id="uname" value=<?php echo $uname;?> />
    <input type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value=<?php echo $price;?> />
    <input type="text" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#submit').click(function(){
     $('#frm1').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Closing tags, or the shortcut, are not required in HTML for *input* and several other tags.